# JQGrid - Changing the width of a column dynamically

Tags: javascript, jqgrid

I understand that the width of each column of jqgrid is defined using `colModel` parameter. Assuming I want to resize a column after I click a button, how can I perform this?

Comment: This answer gives a nice plugin to do that : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20012365/how-to-adjust-the-column-width-of-jqgrid-after-the-data-is-loaded/20030652#20030652

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can set the new width of the column using two methods – setColProp and setGridWidth.

Here is example of setting new width of the column amount:

```
$("#mygrid").jqGrid('setColProp','amount',{width:new_width});

var gw = $("#mygrid").jqGrid('getGridParam','width');

$("#mygrid").jqGrid('setGridWidth',gw);
```

P.S. Note that in order to work this a shrinkToFit should be true, or you should call setGridWidth with second parameter true

Comment: This solution works, except that I needed to use "widthOrg" instead of "width" in the call to 'setColProp'.

Comment: this solution wont work in jqgrid 4.5.2... in the source it explicty says that.

Comment: This solution and telb's remark on `widthOrg` still work for jqGrid 4.5.4 (the current version).

Answer (score 5):

Hello this can be done in two steps:

a) Change width of header cell:

`$('.ui-jqgrid-labels > th:eq(0)').css('width','200px')`

b) Change width of cells in column:

`$('#grid tr').find("td:eq(0)").each(function(){$(this).css('width','200px');})`

Comment: Using something like this `$('#grid').parents('.ui-jqgrid-view').find('.ui-jqgrid-labels > th:eq(0)').css('width','200px');` will only change a specified grid [eg: $('#grid')] instead off all grids if you have more than one.

Comment: Awsome , in my case these two lines are Woking 
`$('#list_requisitos tr').find("td:eq(4)").each(function(){$(this).css('width','200px');})
$('.jqg-first-row-header').find("th:eq(4)").each(function(){$(this).css('width','200px');})`
this is because I tried lot but in shrinkFit = ON this is the only way for spacific column width

Answer (score 4):

This code doesn't affect on table view, only change `width` property of column in `colModel`:

```
$("#[grid_id]").jqGrid('setColProp','[column_name]',{width:[new_width]});
```

Yo can change column `width` dynamically with this **([column_index] starts from 1)**:

```
$('#[grid_id]_[column_name], #[grid_id] tr.jqgfirstrow td:nth-child([column_index])').width([new_width])
```

Answer (score 2):

Example, if you have many columns to change:

In this case, after the jqgrid is getting built, you can just go to the table getting generated and manually change all the column widths of column header and the respective data without writing tedious code.

```
        var tabColWidths ='70px|125px|125px|125px|125px|125px|125px|125px|125px|125px|125px|125px|125px|125px|125px|125px|125px|125px|125px|125px|125px|125px';

function reDefineColWidth(){
        var widthsArr = tabColWidths.split('|');

    for(var j=0; j < widthsArr.length ; j++ ){
            $('.ui-jqgrid-labels > th:eq('+j+')').css('width',widthsArr[j]);
            $('#grid tr').find('td:eq('+j+')').each(function(){$(this).css('width',widthsArr[j]);})
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#gbox_list_requisitos').css('width','1300px');
$('#gview_list_requisitos').css('width','1300px');
$('#gview_list_requisitos').css('width','1300px');
$('.ui-state-default').css('width','1300px');
$('.ui-jqgrid-hdiv').css('width','1300px');
$('.ui-jqgrid-bdiv').css('width','1300px');
$('#pager_requisitos').css('width','1300px');
```

Here is my answer It can be fixed 
I was facing same problem like in shrinkFit = true, I got 2 horizontal scroll bars
and this solution is working, instead of 1300 you can use window width

my table id is `list_requisitos`
 and pageer id is `pager_requisitos`