# Change Columns width problems

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

I'm not able to change the columns width in the latest jqGrid version (4.4.1).

In the 3.8.2 version I used this code to change columns width (and it works well):

grid options:

```
shrinkToFit = true;
```

I put the following code in the `loadComplete` section.

First of all I changed the columns width:

```
$("#gridId").jqGrid('setColProp',"colname",{width:new_width});
```

and then I changed the grid width

```
$("#gridId").jqGrid('setGridWidth', newGridWidth);
```

and the grid was properly rendered.

I already tried to use the 4.3.2 modified release:
[JQGrid: Resize Grid Width After Column Resized](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9593101/jqgrid-resize-grid-width-after-column-resized)
but with no success.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found a bug into `grid.base.js`, if you apply this fix grid resizing with different columns width will works.

Into setGridWidth I've changed both lines:

```
cw = this.widthOrg;

width

cw = this.width;
```

Answer (score 2):

The solution proposed by Alberto still works for jqGrid 4.5.4 (the current version). However, a better solution was suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12172228/2842067): you need to replace `width:` with `widthOrg:` in

```js
$("#gridId").jqGrid('setColProp',"colname",{width:new_width});
```

The second solution also works for jqGrid 4.5.4.