# Change Column width with setColProp not working

Tags: asp.net, ajax, jqgrid

I try to change the **width** of a Column inside an ajax request:

```
 $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "Main.aspx/GetColWidth",
    data: {},
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function (a) {
        $("#UsersGrid").jqGrid("setColProp", "colname", {width: 100});
    }
});
```

If I call the **getGridParam** right after I call setColProp, I can see the new width, but nothing changes on the table. The Column has its old width.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

jqGrid don't provide any method which can be used to change the `width` after the grid is created. The method `setColProp` just applies the changes on the corresponding item of `colModel`, but it *don't applies the changes on the grid.

Nevertheless I wrote `setColWidth` which allows to change the column width. You can download the latest version of `setColWidth` from [github](https://github.com/OlegKi/jqGrid-plugins), include `jQuery.jqGrid.setColWidth.js` file after `jquery.jqGrid.min.js`. After that you can use

```js
$("#UsersGrid").jqGrid("setColWidth", "colname", newColumnWidth);
```

or

```js
$("#UsersGrid").jqGrid("setColWidth", "colname", newColumnWidth, false);
```

which don't adjust the width of the grid additionally after changing the size of the column. The first call (without `false`) is especially suitable in case of usage `shrinkToFit: true` option.

You can find the demo which uses`setColWidth` in [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20030652/315935) for which I initially developed the `setColWidth` method.

**UPDATE**: `setColWidth` is the part of [free jqGrid](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid). Thus one need just update to the latest version of jqGrid to be able to use `setColWidth` method.

Comment: Your code works perfect. Thanks Oleg. Now i need to figure out myself why if I use the code inside  ajax doesn't change the widths