# Jqgrid Get and Set column width

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

I have looked around other answers on here and had no luck. I have a jqgrid and i want to persist the column width. I save the width on the resize Stop event to a db and then every time the grid is loaded i set the width in the colModel to the width stored in the db but it is never the correct width. For example i have 420 stored as the width in the db for the column name but when i load the grid and check the col model it has a width of 150. Ive checked and made sure the correct value is being passed back so i cant understand why jqgrid wont use it.

Im not sure why but its as though jqgrid is ignoring the width i pass in the colmodel. I have included the cut down version of my jqgrid below. Thank you for any help.

```
$('#ProjectTable').jqGrid({
        datatype: 'json',
        url: '<%= Url.Action("projectGridData", "SampleSelection") %>',
        mType: 'POST',
        colNames: [
        htmlDecode("<%=Atmis.EncodedLabel("Sample.Project.ProjectId", "ID") %>"),
        "",
         htmlDecode("<%=Atmis.EncodedLabel("Sample.Project.Name", "Name") %>"),
          htmlDecode("<%=Atmis.EncodedLabel("Sample.Project.Code", "Code") %>"),
           htmlDecode("<%=Atmis.EncodedLabel("Sample.Project.Manager", "Manager") %>"),
              htmlDecode("<%=Atmis.EncodedLabel("Sample.Project.StartDate", "Start Date") %>"),
               htmlDecode("<%=Atmis.EncodedLabel("Sample.Project.CompletionDate", "CompletionDate") %>"),
               htmlDecode("<%=Atmis.EncodedLabel("Sample.Project.Remark", "Remark") %>"),
               htmlDecode("<%=Atmis.EncodedLabel("Sample.Project.Status", "Status") %>"),
               ""
               ],
        colModel:[
        {name: 'FieldProjectId', width: 10, align: 'center', key: true, search: false, hidden: true},
        {name: 'Edit', width: 30, search: false, sortable: false, align: 'center'},
        {name: 'Name', width: ColumnManager.GetColumnWidth('ProjectTable', 'Name'), index: 'Name', editable: true},
        {name: 'Code', width: 50, index: 'Code', editable: true},
        {name: 'Manager', width: 100, index: 'Manager', editable: true},
        {name: 'StartDate', width: 65, index: 'StartDate', search: true, formatter : 'date', formatoptions: { srcformat: 'm/d/Y', newformat: 'd/m/Y'}, editable: true,editoptions : { dataInit: function (elem) { $(elem).datepicker({
                        changeMonth: true,
                        changeYear: true,
                        showWeek: true,
                        onSelect : function () { $('#ProjectTable')[0].triggerToolbar(); }
                    }).keyup(function(e) {
                        if (e.keyCode == 8 || e.keyCode == 46) {
                            $.datepicker._clearDate(this);
                        }
                    });
                }}, searchoptions: { dataInit: function (elem) { $(elem).datepicker({
                        changeMonth: true,
                        changeYear: true,
                        showWeek: true,
                        onSelect : function () { $('#ProjectTable')[0].triggerToolbar(); }
                    }).keyup(function(e) {
                        if (e.keyCode == 8 || e.keyCode == 46) {
                            $.datepicker._clearDate(this);
                        }
                    });
                } }},
        {name: 'CompletedDate', width: 65, index: 'CompletedDate', formatter : 'date', formatoptions: { srcformat: 'm/d/Y', newformat: 'd/m/Y'}, editable: true, editoptions : { dataInit: function (elem) { $(elem).datepicker({
                        changeMonth: true,
                        changeYear: true,
                        showWeek: true,
                        onSelect : function () { $('#ProjectTable')[0].triggerToolbar(); }
                    }).keyup(function(e) {
                        if (e.keyCode == 8 || e.keyCode == 46) {
                            $.datepicker._clearDate(this);
                        }
                    });
                }}, sorttype:'date' , searchoptions: { dataInit: function (elem) { $(elem).datepicker({
                        changeMonth: true,
                        changeYear: true,
                        showWeek: true,
                        onSelect : function () { $('#ProjectTable')[0].triggerToolbar(); }
                    }).keyup(function(e) {
                        if (e.keyCode == 8 || e.keyCode == 46) {
                            $.datepicker._clearDate(this);
                        }
                    });
                }}},
        {name: 'Remark', width: 200, index: 'Remark', search: false, editable: true},
        {name: 'Status', width: 95, index: 'Status', editable: true },
        {name: 'Delete', width: 20, search: false, sortable: false, align: 'center'},
        ],
        caption: htmlDecode("<%=Atmis.EncodedLabel("Sample.Project.Caption", "Project") %>"),
        width: $('#tabs-projects').width() - 20,
        //shrinkToFit: false,
        sortname: 'FieldProjectId',
        loadui: 'block',
        rowNum: 20,
        rowList: [10,25,50,100,200],
        sortorder : 'desc',
        headertitles:true,
        resizeStop: function(width, index) { 
             var colModel = $("#ProjectTable").jqGrid('getGridParam','colModel');

             ColumnManager.SetColumnWidth("ProjectTable",colModel[index].name,width);
             alert(JSON.stringify(colModel));

        },
        height: 'auto',
        viewrecords: true,
        toolbar: [true, "top"],
        pager: $('#ProjectPager')
                                }
                            });
                    }, 1000);

                });
        }
        }
        ).filterToolbar();

        $('#ProjectTable').navGrid('#ProjectPager', {
        search: false,
        add: false,
        edit: false,
        del: false,
        refresh: true
        });
```

And the functions to set and get the column width:

```
       var ColumnManager = {
        SetColumnWidth : function(grid, column, value)
        {
             $.ajax({
                    url: '<%= Url.Action("SaveGridColumWidthPreference", "SampleSelection") %>',
                    dataType: 'json',
                    type: 'POST',
                    data: { 
                        gridID: grid,
                        width: value,
                        colName: column 
                    },
                    success:function(data) {
                    }
                });
        },
        GetColumnWidth : function(grid, column)
        {
             $.ajax({
                    url: '<%= Url.Action("GetGridColumWidthPreference", "SampleSelection") %>',
                    dataType: 'json',
                    type: 'POST',
                    data: { 
                        gridID: grid,
                        colName: column 
                    },
                    success:function(data) {
                        if(data > 0)
                        {
                            alert(data);
                            return data;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            alert(projectDefaults["name"]);
                            return projectDefaults["name"]; //should return default here
                        }
                    }
                });
        },
        ReturnColumnWidth : function(){

        }
    };
```

Comment: Which version of jqGrid you use? Which fork of jqGrid you use ([free jqGrid](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid), [Guriddo jqGrid JS](http://guriddo.net/?page_id=103334) or some old jqGrid in version <=4.7)? Free jqGrid have `setColWidth` method which could be helphul for your scenario. I posted the method `setColWidth` as plugin before strting to develop free jqGrid. Thus you can use it if you can't upgrade to free jqGrid.

Comment: Im using the Guriddo one version 5.0.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't follow [Guriddo jqGrid JS](http://guriddo.net/?page_id=103334) because I developer [free jqGrid](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid) starting which changing license agreement of jqGrid 4.7.1 and renaming it in Guriddo jqGrid JS. Nevertheless I found that Guriddo jqGrid JS 5.0.1, which you use, have [resizeColumn](https://github.com/tonytomov/jqGrid/blob/v5.0.1/js/grid.base.js#L4935) method which do the same as [setColWidth](https://github.com/OlegKi/jqGrid-plugins/blob/master/jQuery.jqGrid.setColWidth.js) which I suggested originally in [the old answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20030652/315935). I included `setColWidth` in the first version of free jqGrid, which I published.

I would recommend you read [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31663268/315935) which included [the demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/OK/ColumnChooserAndLocalStorage2_singleSelect.htm). It seems to me that the demo implements very close requirements to yourth. It saves/restore the grid state (inclusive column width and many other) in `localStorage` of the web browser instead of sending the data via Ajax to the server. I think you can modify the code corresponds your requiremnets.

Comment: Thank you, id forgotten about the license change. Id been using a previous version with the MIT license and updated it recently so i think il move over to the free version you work on. Thank you for the reply Oleg helpful as always :)