# What is p.nv propertty of column in dragEnd() jqgrid?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqgrid

I am curious what is p.nv property in jqgrid columns. This is being using inside `dragEnd()` function in jqgrid.

```
dragEnd: function() {
this.hDiv.style.cursor = "default";
if(this.resizing) {
 var idx = this.resizing.idx,
 nw = this.headers[idx].newWidth || this.headers[idx].width;
 nw = parseInt(nw,10);
 this.resizing = false;
 $("#rs_m"+$.jgrid.jqID(p.id)).css("display","none");
 p.colModel[idx].width = nw;
 this.headers[idx].width = nw;
 this.headers[idx].el.style.width = nw + "px";
 this.cols[idx].style.width = nw+"px";
  if(this.footers.length>0) {this.footers[idx].style.width = nw+"px";}
   if(p.forceFit===true){
  nw = this.headers[idx+p.nv].newWidth || this.headers[idx+p.nv].width;
  this.headers[idx+p.nv].width = nw;
  this.headers[idx+p.nv].el.style.width = nw + "px";
  this.cols[idx+p.nv].style.width = nw+"px";
  if(this.footers.length>0) {this.footers[idx+p.nv].style.width = nw+"px";}
   p.colModel[idx+p.nv].width = nw;
 }
```

Comment: It's a very strange question. Do you want to understand the code of `dragStart`, `dragMove`, `dragEnd`? **Which version of jqGrid you use?** I can comment the meaning of `nv` if you want. The `nv` will be used **only if `forceFit: true`** is set. `nv` is the index of the next visible column after the column which will be resized. The parameter `nv` will be set inside of `mousedown`. By the way I rewrote the code in free jqGrid (see [here](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid/blob/v4.13.3/js/grid.base.js#L2931-L2949)) using additional `resizeColumn` function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that you included the first part of the code `dragEnd` from some old version of jqGrid. At least the code of `dragEnd` from version 4.7 looks the same.

The parameter `nv` (p.nv) will be initialized to 0 initially (see [here](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid/blob/v4.7.0/js/grid.base.js#L848)) and it will be used inside of `dragMove` (see [here](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid/blob/v4.7.0/js/grid.base.js#L914)) and `dragEnd` (see [here](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid/blob/v4.7.0/js/grid.base.js#L941-L946)) **only if the option `forceFit: true` is set**. In the case the option `nv` will be set to the index in `colModel` of the next visible column (`nv` come from the *next visible*) after the resizing column inside of `mousedown` event handler (see [here](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid/blob/v4.7.0/js/grid.base.js#L2683-L2688)) before `dragStart` be started.

By the way I rewrote the code in [free jqGrid](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid) to allow to move separater between the columns *outer of* the grid. It's very helpful during resizing of the last column of the grid.

Comment: yeah its old version i guess. I wanted to know about this because for setting the column width i am using your provided solution http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20012365/how-to-adjust-the-column-width-of-jqgrid-after-the-data-is-loaded.  > I am using setColWidth with false since i want to hold the original grid. Issue is when i am dragging a column and while reszing again i am calling the setColWidth with false, since p.nv is changed to some value from 0 ,i am ending up updating width of a column either which is wrong or not present and getting a script error.

Comment: @user2009877: `setColWidth` is the part of jqGrid methods in free jqGrid fork, which I develop. Probably you need to reset `nv` to 0 before call of `setColWidth`.